# TextView programmatically added to TableLayout doesn't match parent's width

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I want to create a `TableLayout` with two columns. The first column would display drawable inside `ImageView` and should have the width of the picture. The second column should take all the remaining space (so match row's width).

```
TableLayout(context).apply {
    myList.forEach {
        val tableRow = TableRow(context)
        tableRow.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN)

        tableRow.addView(ImageView(context).apply {
            setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_blabla)
        })

        tableRow.addView(TextView(context).apply {
            text = it.code.toString()
            setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW)
            layoutParams = TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                                 TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
        })

        addView(tableRow)
    }

    myLinearLayout.addView(this)
}
```

Table layout is programmatically added to the linear layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/myLinearLayout"/>
```

As a result, I get two columns but both have the width of the content. The row has a green background so I can see that it has the width of the screen but the second column with yellow background has the width of the text displayed inside.

[image]

Any idea how can I set the second column width to take all that space?

Comment: Are you adding table layout to linear layout at the end?

Comment: Yes. There are going to be multiple tables with different designs so they're all added to linear layout.

Comment: Can you please post xml code for your linear layout?

Comment: I updated my post.

Comment: Are you sure that `TableLayout` itself has the MATCH_PARENT value for its layout_width? You can also set `layout_weight="1"` for `TableLayout`

Comment: I've added weight param to layoutParams for the second column and it solved the issue. Thank you @Steyrix

Comment: Great! I posted an answer, you can accept it, so the other people, who will face the similar issue, will be able to easily find the workaround

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `layout_weigth="1"` attribute to the column, it will assign additional importance to the view, so the column will be able to fill more space on the screen.